# Expected number of letters in the post box that has lower number of letters given that N letters are to be distributed. (Crazy Postman Problem)

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

[This is a problem from BrainStellar](https://brainstellar.com/puzzles/probability/215)

I assumed $E[X_j]$ to be the expected number of letters in the box when $j^{th}$ trial happens.

So the problem reduces to finding $E[X_{j+1}]$(in this case)

$E[X_{j+1}] = E[E[X_{j+1}|X_{j}]]$.

$E[X_{j+1}|X_{j}] = (X_{j} + 1)(X_j/j) + X_j (1- (X_j/j))$.

Which gives,

$E[X_{j+1}|X_{j}] = (X_j/j) + X_j$;

So now we have the recurrence relation,

$E[X_{j+1}] = E[X_j/j + X_j]$ , given that $E[X_1] = 1$

Using this I am getting the answer as $n-1$ which is clearly wrong.

I would appreciate if you could find out the fault in the process.

PS: I know I did not use the property that the lower box has to have less number of letters. I did not know where to put it

Comment: You've miscounted the total number of letters that have been distributed after the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ distribution, which is $\ j+1\ $ not $\ j\ $.  The corrected recursion then gives you $\ E\left[X_{N-1}\right]=\frac{N}{2}\ $. What you find with this recursion is just the expected number of letters in a specific box, which is, of course, the same for both boxes by symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ X_j $ and $\ Y_j\ $ be the number of letters in the two boxes after the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ distribution of letters, and  $\ \displaystyle D_j=\left|X_j-Y_j\right|\ $. Then the expected number of letters in the box with no more letters than the other after the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ distribution is $\ E\left[\frac{j+1-D_j}{2}\right]\ $, and
\begin{align}
\ \\
E\left[D_j\right|\left.D_{j-1}\right]&=\displaystyle\frac{D_{j-1}}{j}\left(D_{j-1}-1\right)+ \left(1-\frac{D_{j-1}}{j}\right)\left(D_{j-1}+1\right)\\
&=1+\frac{(j-2)}{j} D_{j-1}
\end{align}
for $\ j\ge 2\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\ \\
E\left[D_j\right] &=E\left[E\left[D_j\right|\left.D_{j-1}\right]\right]\\
&=1+\frac{(j-2)}{j} E\left[D_{j-1}\right]\ .
\end{align}
Starting from $\ j=2\ $, the first few terms of this recursion are $\ 1,\frac{4}{3}, \frac{5}{3}, 2, \dots\ $, suggesting $\ \frac{j+1}{3}\ $ for the general term, which is easily confirmed by induction.
The quantity you're looking for is therefore
\begin{align}
\ \\
E\left[\frac{N-D_{N-1}}{2}\right]&=\frac{N}{3}\ .\\
\ 
\end{align}